# interface interaction in C

Tags: c

I have a monolithic C file with implementation of network layer and business logic and I want to split it into files with network and business logic respectively.

I want to unit test only business logic, without going deep into network layer. And here is a problem. In this case methods from file A will call methods from file B and vice-versa.

I need to substitute methods from network layer files with stubs. In C++, C# network layer can be implemented with interface class, but how can it be done in C? Is there an elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

If your code is contained in different .c files then you can simply substitute a different .c file when you build your tests.

Any other solution is working too hard.

Answer (score 0):

"abc.h"

```
int function a();
int function b();
```

//end of abc.h

"new.c"

```
#include"abc.h"

int function a(){
//do something
return 0;
}
```

//end of new.c

"main.c"

```
#include"abc.h"
int main(){
a();
return 0;
}
```